# Convergence of a net in a Hilbert space

Tags: operator-theory, representation-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Suppose $\phi:A\rightarrow B(H)$ is a nonzero $*$ homomorphism, where $A$ is a nonunital $C^*$ algebra, $H$ is a Hilbert space, $\{x_{i}\}$ is a net of unit vectors in $H$, does there exist $a_0\in A$ such that $\{\phi(a_0)x_{i}\}$ is norm convergent to a nonzero element?

Comment: Of course. Take $a_0=0$.

Comment: Actually,I want to get the conclusion that $\{\phi(a_0)x_{i}\}$ is norm convergent to a nonzero element.

Comment: I have reedited the question.

Comment: I suppose taking some point of an approximate unit might get you somewhere, with some non-degeneracy added to your homomorphiam?

Answer (score 1):

No.  For instance, suppose $(x_i)$ is a net which accumulates at every point in the unit sphere of $H$ (for instance, if $H$ is separable, you could just take a sequence formed by a countable dense subset).  If $a\in B(H)$ is such that $(ax_i)$ converges to some vector $v$, then by continuity we must have $ax=v$ for all $x$ in the unit sphere.  This is obviously impossible by linearity of $a$ unless $v=0$.